# Are linewidth of the laser source and vacuum fluctuations measured using the homodyne detection independent?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics, randomness

For Vacuum fluctuations based QRNG source, how will the linewidth of the laser source affects the shot noise. If we decrease the linewidth of the laser source, will we get a better output.